# What's faster in this case: searching a list or dict?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

Say I have a text, 50,000 words, and I want to check every word in the text to see if it's been encountered yet. Would it be faster to:

```
a)  double_checker = []
    for word in text:
        if word not in double_checker:
            double_checker.append(word)
            [perform operations]

b)  double_checker = {'a':[], 'b':[], 'c':[], 'd':[], 'e':[], 'f':[], 
                      'g':[], 'h':[], 'i':[], 'j':[], 'k':[], 'l':[], 
                      'm':[], 'n':[], 'o':[], 'p':[], 'q':[], 'r':[],
                      's':[], 't':[], 'u':[], 'v':[], 'w':[], 'x':[],
                      'y':[], 'z':[]}
    for word in text:
        if word not in double_checker[word[0].lower()]:
            double_checker[word[0].lower()].append(word)
            [perform operations]
```

I'll be testing this myself, but my code takes about an hour to run so I was wondering if there were a theoretical calculation. I know the list is O(N) and a dict works off a faster hash, but the dict method has to also search through lists roughly 1/26th the size (obviously there will be more 'e' entries than 'z') AND access the 0th element of every word twice. For what I'm doing it isn't feasible to pre-sort.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Place the full word (not only first character) in the dict (or maybe a set).

Comment: *"I'll be testing this myself, but my code takes about an hour to run"* - a question which is only answerable during a period of one hour is not a valuable addition to this site.  Further, you can simply cut your input data set in half to reduce testing time.

Comment: @MichaelButscher as opposed to 26 lists arranged by alphabet letter, it'll be faster to create (somewhat less than) 50,000 empty value'd keys in a dict and look through that_dict.keys()?

Comment: @JohnZwinck sorry I ruined your website.

Comment: Also, it could be that a `set` is the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the word itself as the dictionary key.  Much faster.

```
double_checker = {}
for word in text:
    if word not in double_checker:
        double_checker[word] = 1
    else:
        double_checker[word] += 1
    [do operations]
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you for the insight, wouldn't have occurred to me to do it this way.